# How to use SensorSimulator with AndEngine

Tags: android, andengine

On http://code.google.com/p/openintents/wiki/SensorSimulator it says to put code in onCreate() and onResume(), however, there are no such methods in the AndEngine framework (GLES2.0).

I know I'm doing it wrong, what is the best way of getting SensorSimulator to work with AndEngine?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can still override the standard android activity life cycle callback methods in AndEngine. Like SVS said, BseGameActivity in AndEngine has implemented those callback methods for you. You can override them, but be sure to remember calling the super constructor.
Beside the SensorSimulator, if you have a real device, there is also another way (which is officially supported by Android) to simulate the sensor. See http://tools.android.com/tips/hardware-emulation for details.

Answer (score 0):

BaseGameActivity (or other AndEngine activities) is extension of Activity. That's why use onCreate and onResume in AndEngine as well as you use Activity. They are present there.